# React Native - Nested array in AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I've been trying this for days, what I'm targeting is to display states in a nested array form and save it at the same time using AsyncStorage. I figure out to display a single state and save it also, but with nested array it won't work and there's no error.

Here is my target:

[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU6Jw.png)

The "Name" and the "Price" should come from my api, but for the sake of simplicity I'll just use some simple array without api.

Here is my code:

Store.js

```
const isAndroid = Platform.OS == "android";
const viewPadding = 10;

export default class Store extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          tasks: [{
            id: "Ford" ,
            price: "123"
          }],
          text: "",
        }
    }

  changeTextHandler = (text) => {
    this.setState({ text: text });
  };

  addTask = () => {
    let notEmpty = this.state.text.trim().length > 0;

    if (notEmpty) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => {
          let { tasks, text, id, price } = prevState;
          return {
            tasks: tasks.concat({ key: tasks.length, text: text, id: id, price: price }),
            id: id,
            price: price,
            text: "",
          };
        },
        () => Tasks.save(this.state.tasks)
      );
    }
  };

  deleteTask = i => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        let tasks = prevState.tasks.slice();

        tasks.splice(i, 1);

        return { tasks: tasks };
      },
      () => Tasks.save(this.state.tasks)
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Keyboard.addListener(
      isAndroid ? "keyboardDidShow" : "keyboardWillShow",
      e => this.setState({ viewPadding: e.endCoordinates.height + viewPadding })
    );
    Keyboard.addListener(
      isAndroid ? "keyboardDidHide" : "keyboardWillHide",
      () => this.setState({ viewPadding: viewPadding })
    );
    Tasks.all(tasks => this.setState({ tasks: tasks || [] }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[styles.container, { paddingBottom: this.state.viewPadding }]}
      >
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={this.state.tasks}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.listItemCont}>
                        <Text>
                        {item.id}
                        {item.price}
                        {item.text}
                        </Text>
                        <Button title="X" onPress={() => this.deleteTask(index)} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.hr}/>
                </View>
            }
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={this.changeTextHandler}
          onSubmitEditing={this.addTask}
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder="Add Tasks"
          returnKeyType="done"
          returnKeyLabel="done"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

let Tasks = {
  convertToArrayOfObject(tasks, callback) {
    return callback(
      tasks ? tasks.split("||").map((task, i) => ({ key: i, text: task })) : []
    );
  },
  convertToStringWithSeparators(tasks) {
    return tasks.map(task => task.text).join("||");
  },
  all(callback) {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem("TASKS", (err, tasks) =>
      this.convertToArrayOfObject(tasks, callback)
    );
  },
  save(tasks) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("TASKS", this.convertToStringWithSeparators(tasks));
  },
};
```